# Do finite exchangeable random sequences behave asymptotically independently?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limits-and-convergence, random-permutations

Let $(X_{n,k})_{k=1,\ldots,n}^{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(Y_{n,k})_{k=1,\ldots,n}^{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be triangular arrays of row-wise exchangeable random variables, that is for any $n$ and permutation $\sigma \in S_n$
$$
(X_{n,1},\ldots,X_{n,n}) \stackrel{d}{=} (X_{n,\sigma(1)},\ldots,X_{n,\sigma(n)})
$$
I am trying to understand if sample statistics of the two behave independently (in terms of convergence in probability) when $X_{n,i}$ and $Y_{n,i}$ are independent.

Starting with the simplest case.
Suppose that we know the following converge to constants in probability
$$
Z_n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}} a_1 \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
Z_n' = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}^2 \xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}} a_2
$$
$$
W_n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_{n,i} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}} b_1 \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
W_n' = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_{n,i}^2 \xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}} b_2
$$
If $\{X_{n,i}\}$ and $\{Y_{n,i}\}$ are independent, is it true that
$$
V_n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}Y_{n,i} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}} a_1b_1
$$

?

---

If convergence of $Z_n,W_n$ is in $L^2$ and $Z_n',W_n'$ in $L^1$, then the answer is yes. First we have $\mathbb{E}(Z_n^2) \to a_1^2$.
Because $\mathbb{E}(Z_n') \to a_2$, we can control the diagonal terms in $Z_n^2$, so that
$$
\mathbb{E}(Z_n^2)
\cong
\frac1{n^2}\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n}_{i\neq j} \
\mathbb{E}(X_{n,i}X_{n,j})
\cong
\mathbb{E}(X_{n,1}X_{n,2}) \to a_1^2
$$
and the same for $Y_{n,k}$.
Now $\mathbb{E}(V_n) = a_1b_1$, and we get
$$
\mathbb{E}( V_n^2 )
=
\frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(X_{n,1}^2)\mathbb{E}(Y_{n,1}^2)
+
\frac1{n^2}\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n}_{i\neq j} \
\mathbb{E}(X_{n,1}X_{n,2})
\mathbb{E}(Y_{n,1}Y_{n,2})
\to
a_1^2 b_1^2
$$
so we have convergence in probability by Chebyshev. Of course this is the situation when the arrays are i.i.d. sequences with second moments.